# dont apply normal redirect rule if call is from a specific subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have a subdomain which is added as a serverAlias to the main domain. I am using this subdomain only for static content such as images and js, so I dont want the subdomain to follow rewrite rules and load index.php if a file is not found, I want it to show generic 404 page which is default from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted not to apply the rule for my subdomain, this code worked for me

> modifying bradym's block as example

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^static.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} static.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) - [R=404,L]
```